# ¿Podrían ayudarme con el Checkout de compra?

Tags: php, html

, Hola, resulta que estoy editando una página de ventas para una tarea en la escuela, le agregué un panel de admin, entre otra cosas, pero no eh podido arreglar algo. 
Cuando elijo el producto y lo mando al carrito, me pone un cartel de paypal, la cosa es que está armado con paypal, o sea, si yo decido comprar, tengo que ingresar mi cuenta de paypal y ahi después de pagar, la página lo guarda en la BD como comprado, yo quisiera reemplazarlo con el formulario de ingreso de tarjetas que hice. Es posible? estes es el codigo:

```
else if(isset($_SESSION["uid"])){
                    //Paypal checkout form
                    echo '
                        </form>
                        <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                            <input type="hidden" name="business" value="shoppingcart@khanstore.com">
                            <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">';

                            $x=0;
                            $sql = "SELECT a.product_id,a.product_title,a.product_price,a.product_image,b.id,b.qty FROM products a,cart b WHERE a.product_id=b.p_id AND b.user_id='$_SESSION[uid]'";
                            $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                                $x++;
                                echo    
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$x.'" value="'.$row["product_title"].'">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="item_number_'.$x.'" value="'.$x.'">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$x.'" value="'.$row["product_price"].'">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$x.'" value="'.$row["qty"].'">';
                                }

                            echo   
                                '<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost/project1/payment_success.php"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://localhost/project1/payment_success.php">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost/project1/cancel.php"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="'.$_SESSION["uid"].'"/>
                                    <input style="float:right;margin-right:80px;" type="image" name="submit"
                                        src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/blue-rect-paypalcheckout-60px.png" alt="PayPal Checkout"
                                        alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
                                </form>';
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, si se requiere algo más para poder entender mi problema, diganlo por favor.

Comment: Para empezar ¿Qué pasarela de pagos para las tarjetas vas a usar? ¿y porque no quieres usar PayPal? si es mas fácil de implementar y cómodo para los usuarios.

Comment: Si, lo sé, es mucho más fácil, pero el profesor se encaprichó en la idea de utilizar tarjetas, no es que yo no quiera, es más, el sistema está hecho para que con solo registrar mi cuenta de paypal, ya puede la gente comprar a través de la página. 

¿Qué sería una pasarela de pagos? no entiendo mucho

Answer (score 1):

Uh... nos estás mostrando el formulario que usa paypal, pero no el formulario que utilizaría una tarjeta de crédito. No podemos inventarlo por ti.

Dicho esto, una pasarela de pago o payment gateway es un servicio que te permite cursar el pago y es intermediario entre un ecommerce y el cliente. Te cobran una comisión pero te olvidas del problema de almacenar la data de la tarjeta de crédito del cliente.

Algunas pasarelas de pago como Paypal manejan una billetera virtual que por debajo está enlazada a una o más tarjetas de crédito.

A lo mejor tu profesor quiere algo que te permita digitar directamente la tarjeta, pero para eso simplemente puedes usar otra pasarela. Por ejemplo [2Checkout](https://www.2checkout.com/)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero esto ocurre **siempre** en un overlay de ellos. Un ecommerce **no debe** almacenar esa información, eso es una práctica muy peligrosa y en algunos países simplemente está regulatoriamente prohibido. En donde se permite, te exigen contar con la certificación [PCI_DSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_DSS). Esa certificación demora meses en ser aprobada si es que tu empresa realmente cumple.

Si tu profesor queda satisfecho con el uso de 2Checkout, entonces revisa el API de ese proveedor y darás con la solución. Si tu profesor insiste en que uds guarden la información en su base de datos local, por favor mándalo para acá.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder realizar cobros con una tarjeta lo mejor es utilizar una pasarela de pagos.

Una entidad que se encarga de procesar los pagos, de esta forma tu no guardas datos bancarios de tus clientes los cuales son altamente sensibles si no que los envías de manera encriptada y la pasarela es la que hace el proceso de comunicación con el banco por una comisión.

Se pueden usar muchas pasarelas pues hay muchas compañías yo uso openpay.

para ello primero tendrías que crearte una cuenta de desarrollador donde tendrás acceso a una cuenta para hacer pruebas (sandbox) y tus llaves para acceder a la API.

funciona mas o menos así (usando OpenPay como ejemplo);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasos:

1. Implementación del sistema antifraude generando un
   "device_session_id"
2. Tokenización de la tarjeta de crédito o débito usando la librería
   Openpay.js
3. Toda la información de la compra se envía a tu servidor
4. Desde tu servidor se crea el cargo en Openpay
5. Openpay envía la instrucción de cargo al banco emisor y regresa la respuesta

   las instrucciones para la implementación las encuentras aquí: 
   [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.openpay.mx/docs/card-charge.html)

Pero la parte del php que es la que te interesa quedaría mas o menos así:

```
    <?php

try{

    require '../../../libs/openpay/sdk/Openpay.php';
    require '../../../libs/carrito/Carrito.php';

    //tu archivo de conexion a la base de datos

    $conn = require_once 'connexion.php';  

    //tu clase de carrito dependera de tu implementación
    $carrito = new Carrito();


    //tus datos de desarrollador 
      $openpay = Openpay::getInstance('id', 'clave');
      Openpay::setProductionMode(false);

    //los datos del cliente
    $customer = [
        'name' => $_SESSION['nombre_session'],
        // 'last_name' => $_SESSION['nombre_session'],
        'phone_number' => $_SESSION['telefono_session'],
        'email' => $_SESSION['email_session'],
    ];

    //lo que vas a cobrar
    $total = $carrito->precio_total();

    $chargeData = [
        'method' => 'card',
        'source_id' => $_POST['token_id'],
        'amount' => (string)$total,
        'description' => 'Pago tienda en linea',
        'device_session_id' => $_POST['device_session'],
        'customer' => $customer,
    ];


     $charge = $openpay->charges->create($chargeData);

     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors','1');

    $carrito->destroy();
    echo 'Tu orden fue procesada con exito. Revisa en tu Perfil.';

} catch (OpenpayApiTransactionError $e) {
    error_log('ERROR on the transaction: ' . $e->getMessage() .
          ' [error code: ' . $e->getErrorCode() .
          ', error category: ' . $e->getCategory() .
          ', HTTP code: '. $e->getHttpCode() .
          ', request ID: ' . $e->getRequestId() . ']', 0);

        $errores = [
              3001 =>   "La tarjeta fue rechazada.",
              3002 =>   "La tarjeta ha expirado.",
              3003 =>   "La tarjeta no tiene fondos suficientes.",
              3004 =>   "La tarjeta ha sido identificada como una tarjeta robada.",
              3005 =>   "La tarjeta ha sido rechazada por el sistema antifraudes.",
              3001 =>   "La tarjeta fue rechazada.",
              3002 =>   "La tarjeta ha expirado.",
              3003 =>   "La tarjeta no tiene fondos suficientes."

                  ];

        echo ($errores[$e->getErrorCode()]);
        echo '</br>';
        echo $e->getMessage();

} catch (OpenpayApiRequestError $e) {
    error_log('ERROR on the request: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);


} catch (OpenpayApiConnectionError $e) {
    error_log('ERROR while connecting to the API: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);


} catch (OpenpayApiAuthError $e) {
    error_log('ERROR on the authentication: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);


} catch (OpenpayApiError $e) {
    error_log('ERROR on the API: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);


} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log('Error on the script: ' . $e->getMessage(), 0);

}

?>
```